# Google Play Games interactive sign-in prompt implementation?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm working on a mobile game, and I need the users to log in to their Play Games account to use the leaderboard feature. I want the app to prompt for their account when MainActivity is launched. I followed the steps on the Google developers website and it just doesn't work. The screen dims, as if it was about to prompt for log-in, then it shows a message saying there was an error with the sign-in. Here's my code so far; What am I missing to make it work?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int score = 0;
Button newRound;
TextView scoreText, highScore;
MediaPlayer sound = new MediaPlayer();
ColorStateList oldColors;
int hiScore = 0;
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ImageButton leaderboards;
int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leaderboards = findViewById(R.id.leaderboards);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        enableTooltips();
    }



    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    newRound = findViewById(R.id.button_gen);
    scoreText = findViewById(R.id.score_tv);
    highScore = findViewById(R.id.highScore);

    oldColors =  scoreText.getTextColors();

    int savedScore = preferences.getInt("score", 0);
    int savedHiScore = preferences.getInt("hiScore", 0);

    scoreText.setText(""+savedScore);
    highScore.setText("High score: "+savedHiScore);
    score = savedScore;
    hiScore = savedHiScore;

    if(score >= 1){
        changeColor();
    }

    newRound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            newRound();
        }
    });

    startSignInIntent();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

private void startSignInIntent() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "Sign in error";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check the [add sign-in workflow](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/) for possible things that you missed?

Comment: I did and I don't see anything missing... Plus these steps are for regular Google sign-in while I'm trying to implement a Google Play Games sign-in

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems too you're not  alone but it works for default sign in for some reason.